# Laravel 5 : Facing issue with defining routes

Tags: php, laravel-5

Working on Laravel 5.2 app, My problem with routes I've defined.

*1. Redirect to home*

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => '/','uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
```

*2. Redirect to user profile i.e "www.mydomain.com/samrow"*

```
Route::get('/{username?}', ['as' => '/','uses' => 'HomeController@profile']);
```

**3. Not Redirect to dashboard, its redirect to profile action**

```
Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => '/dashboard','uses' => 'HomeController@dashboard']);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should define midlewares to separate authenticated users from guests. By the way, the `as` parameter is here to name your route, such as `home.dashboard` and not `/dashboard` which is of no use. This allows you to change the path without having to touch any code beside your `routes.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses the first route that matches the request, so the order in which you define them is important.

```
Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => '/dashboard','uses' => 'HomeController@dashboard']);

Route::get('/{username?}', ['as' => '/','uses' => 'HomeController@profile']);

// Catch all should always be last
Route::get('/', ['as' => '/','uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
```